# Count and average even numbers in an array, and check for primes

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

All my display is in ASCII when use (`mov al,2; int 21h`).

I'm only able to check one condition but not all.  How can I check all at the same time and output it?

My assignment is

> Consider a set of pre-stored 1-byte positive integer elements in an
> array. Do the following.
>
> 1. Count the number of elements in your array and display them;
> 2. Identify and display all numbers less than a specific threshold number (you can set this threshold as you wish). If there are none,
>    display a message;
> 3. Identify EVEN numbers, count them and compute their average. Display your result;
> 4. Identify all prime numbers in your array and display them;

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) retag as "homework".  2) Identify the platform and assembler and any other relevant details regarding your build environment. 3) Show your attempts (code and results) and identify the unfavorable behavior (i.e., not just "it doesn't work", but how do the results fail to meet your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to approach something like this in pieces. Considering what you need to do, the first piece I'd probably tackle would be converting a one-byte integer to a string representing that number in decimal.

To do that, you divide the number by 10. The remainder will represent the least significant digit (a number from 0 to 9 inclusive). Convert that to a digit by adding '0'. Repeat that process until your number is 0. To make that easy to print, you might want to start with a buffer of four bytes with a '$' in the last byte. Put the digits into the buffer starting in the last byte before the '$', decrementing a pointer into the buffer for each iteration.

Identifying even numbers is pretty easy: an odd number always has its least significant bit set, and even number doesn't.

Comment: Hi Jerry. thanks for the advice. I knew how to check the even number and prime number. the problem is 1)all my display is in ASCII even I define my arrge using "db byte 1,2,3,4" 2)how to check more than 2 condition at the same time and display it seperately . tks.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through an array of bytes is pretty easy (I'm assuming you should stop when you encounter a negative number, but your situation might vary):

```
mov  esi, pointerToByteArray
loop_start:
  mov  al, [esi]
  cmp  al, 80h
  jge  loop_end

  ; Do your byte-checking code here

  inc  esi
  jmp  loop_start
loop_end:
```

When the loop ends, the total number of elements will be `esi-pointerToByteArray`. Part two you've already done, you didn't realize it. You use the cmp opcode just like:

```
cmp  al, threshold
jge  not_threshhold
; add to threshold counter
not_threshold:
```

Part three is pretty easy too, but will take some knowledge of bit twiddling. You should know that every even number will have the least significant bit clear (the 1's place) so if you remove the top 7 bits you'll either have 1 (for odd numbers) or 0 (for even):

```
mov  bl, al
and  bl, 1
jnz  not_even
; add to even counter
not_even:
```

The easiest way to do part 4 is test each prime less than or equal to 127 (the maximum value of a positive byte):

```
cmp  al, 2
je  is_prime
cmp  al, 3
je  is_prime
cmp  al, 5
je  is_prime
cmp  al, 7
je  is_prime
; all the primes up to 127
jmp not_prime

is_prime:
; add to prime counter
not_prime:
```

Please not that there are much better, more efficient, and elegant ways to check for primeness than that, but it should get the job done. Without knowing more information I can't tell you how to output the information you collect.

Comment: `cmp  al, 80h` / `jge  loop_end` breaks if the value is `>= -128`, i.e. it's always true.  I think you meant `ja`.  But the question said "positive", so presumably zero is a terminator, and you need to use a signed condition to check.  e.g. `test al,al` / `jle break`

Comment: Also, a 256-byte lookup table would be MUCH more efficient than a chain of branches for every prime.  And if you're branching on odd/even, you should use `test al,1`.  But even more efficient is to just count odd numbers and subtract from the length at the end.  `and ax, 1` / `add bx, ax`.  (16-bit count)